# why is findById method of hibernate resulting in "unable to locate persister UnknowEntityTypeException" error?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm hoping you can help me solve this.

I'm trying to use hibernate 5.2 on my web java project. So far, I have managed to make the connection with the database using the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file, also I'm using **hbm** files like the one below to make the class mapping. I'm not using annotations on the models since I'm using **hbm** files. And now I'm trying to test everything by retrieving and object from the database using `findById()` method, but I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: Se ha producido una excepción: java.lang.Throwable: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.upy.model.Usuario
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5000)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.upy.model.Usuario
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:637)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2942)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1800(SessionImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2693)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2679)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1200)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1073)
at com.upy.dao.HibernateDAO.findById(HibernateDAO.java:45)
at com.upy.dao.UsuarioDAO.validarUsuario(UsuarioDAO.java:35)
at com.upy.servlets.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:116)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
... 1 more
```

I don't know why this is happening. This is my method for building the `sessionFactory` in a class called `HibernateDAO`:

```
public class HibernateDAO {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static Session session;

protected void iniciarOperacion()   
{
    try
    {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    catch (HibernateException he)
    {
        System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
}

protected void cerrarOperacion(){
    //getSessionFactory().close();
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
{
    return sessionFactory;
} 

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Object findById(Class clase, Serializable id){
    try{
        iniciarOperacion();
        Object objeto = (Object) getSessionFactory().openSession().get(clase, id);
        if(objeto!=null){
            return objeto;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }catch(RuntimeException ex){
        throw ex;
    }finally{
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

This is my Usuario.java and next the Usuario.hbm.xml:

```
 package com.upy.model;


public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;
private Rol rol;

public Usuario() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Rol getRol() {
    return rol;
}

public void setRol(Rol rol) {
    this.rol = rol;
}
}
```

The Usuario.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
  3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 13-may-2017 19:29:28 by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.upy.model.Usuario" table="usuario" schema="public">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="seqhilo">
            <param name="sequence">public.rol_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="username" type="string">
        <column name="username" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="string">
        <column name="email" />
    </property>     
    <many-to-one name="rol" class="com.upy.model.Rol" fetch="select" 
   lazy="false">
        <column name="rol_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Finally, this is what I'm trying to execute in `UsuarioDAO`:

```
public boolean validarUsuario(String usuario, String password){
    try{
        //iniciarOperacion();
        Usuario user = (Usuario) findById(Usuario.class, usuario);
        if(user == null || !user.getPassword().equals(password)){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }catch(RuntimeException ex){
        throw ex;
    }finally{
        cerrarOperacion();
    }
}
```

The hbm file of `Usuario` is on resources folder inside `src/main/resources` and the model is on `src/main/java/model`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Place the orm XML (mapping scheme) in the META-INF subdirectory along with the persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was such a silly mistake of mine. In the iniciarOperacion() method, im opening and closing the sessionFactory attribute, which should be inmutable. It should be only one sessionFactory per app and one should use session or getCurrentSession() method from there, since those are real connections to the database per request or use.

Thanks either way.